# Selectively multiply elements of a dataframe for a number on the basis of the matching between index and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have a dataframe df of dimension nxn with two different index level, identical for rows and columns. I need to multiply selectively some elements of df on the basis of the matching between the index of rows and the index of columns.

here an example to clarify the question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((5,5)), index=[['A','A','B','B','C'], [1,2,1,2,1]], columns=[['A','A','B','B','C'], [1,2,1,2,1]])
```

now I want to multiply the elements in df in this manner:

- if the index and columns are both identical multiply the relative elements by 1 (ex. A1 and A1);
- if the outer index is equal to the outer column but the inner index is different from the inner column 
  multiply the relative elements by 2 (ex. A1 and A2);
- if the outer index is different from the outer column but inner index is equal to the inner column 
  multiply the relative elements by 3 (ex. B1 and A1);
- if the outer index is different from the outer column and inner index is different from inner column 
  multiply the relative elements by 4 (ex. A2 and C1);

expected output should be a dataframe containing the following elements:

```
     A A B B C
     1 2 1 2 1

A 1  1 2 3 4 3
A 2  2 1 4 3 4
B 1  3 4 1 2 3
B 2  4 3 2 1 4
C 1  3 4 3 4 1
```

Comment: Do you have a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can compare the levels separately. We'll use broadcasting to get all of the comparisons. Then we use `np.select` to create the multiplication mask.

```
d = {}
for level in [0, 1]:
    d[level] = (df.index.get_level_values(level).to_numpy()[:, None] 
                 == df.columns.get_level_values(level).to_numpy()[None, :])

conditions = [d[0] & d[1], d[0] & ~d[1], d[1] & ~d[0]]
choice_list = [1, 2, 3]

mult = np.select(conditions, choice_list, default=4)
```

---

```
df.multiply(mult)

       A         B         C
       1    2    1    2    1
A 1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  3.0
  2  2.0  1.0  4.0  3.0  4.0
B 1  3.0  4.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
  2  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
C 1  3.0  4.0  3.0  4.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

This is rather manual, but will do:

```
offsets = [i + (df.columns.get_level_values(i).values[:,None] != df.index.get_level_values(i).values)
           for i in range(2)]

# output:
df.mul(offsets[0]*2 + offsets[1])
```

Output:

```
       A         B         C
       1    2    1    2    1
A 1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  3.0
  2  2.0  1.0  4.0  3.0  4.0
B 1  3.0  4.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
  2  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
C 1  3.0  4.0  3.0  4.0  1.0
```